# Fatch which emails are on the same lists different tables but same column name email addressess

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have a 11 tables

> email1,email2,email3,email4,email5,email6,email7,email8,email9,email10,email11

and same column name Contact_Email with different email address

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db("email-db",$con);

    $sql = "SELECT Contact_Email FROM email1,email2,email3,email4";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><? echo $row['Contact_Email']; ?></td>
      <td><? echo '<br>'; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
```

actually I want this output

> select all emails from all tables using join   foreach emails as email
>   check if email is in table 1, if yes put yes in td   check if email is
>   in table 2, if yes put yes in td   check if email is in table 3, if
>   yes put yes in td

etc

kindly help me what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just use UNION, following this example:**

```sql
SELECT u.email
FROM email1 AS u
UNION 
SELECT e.email
FROM email2 AS e
```

**In PHP:**

```php
$sql = "SELECT u.email FROM email1 AS u 
UNION SELECT e.email FROM email2 AS e";
$result = mysql_query($sql);while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 { ...}
```

***To avoid MYSQL ERROR "Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'" Please synchronize all email fields to be with equal parameters***